# Set label at specific coordinates in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, coordinate

how can I set the label at specific coordinates in netlogo. I have tried following methods

```
ask people
    [setxy -16 15 ;Defining Positions  
     set label (word (WORD "This is: John " ))   
     set label-color white]
```

; people is my turtle

But setxy moves both my turtle and label to (-16,15). I just want to move the label to these coordinates. The turtle should remain where it was. Any help will be appreciated since I am new to Netlogo and am trying to learn this language as much as I can.Thank you so much

Comment: You don't need to use `word`, here (especially not twice!)

`word` is only needed when you want to convert something else to a string or when you have multiple strings that you want to concatenate.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Yes I had used word and after the sentence "This is: John" I was using a variable, I removed the variable from question to make it as simple as possible but forgot to remove "word" (My mistake). But again thank you for pointing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`label`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#label) is attached to the turtle. It always moves with it.

If you want a label at a fixed position, however, you can use a patch label: [`plabel`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plabel). For example:

```
ask patch -16 15 [
  set plabel "This is: John"
  set plabel-color white
]
```

Another possibility, to get a bit more flexibility, is to create a dummy breed of turtles and use them exclusively for labels:

```
breed [ signs sign ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-signs 1 [
    setxy -9.5 13.5
    set size 0 ; hide the turtle, but not the label
    set label "This is: John"
    set label-color white
  ]
end
```

This way, you can use more precise coordinates and move the labels around if needed.

Comment: Thank you sir. It will do perfectly. You are a blessing :)